# Global component overlay other contents

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

In the Next.js framework I wanted to apply the clipped drawer provided by MUI to the global/every page, so I add the component in the _app.tsx file as follows:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import ClippedDrawer from '../src/ClippedDrawer'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  
  return <>
  <ClippedDrawer /*Drawer and App bar with search field.*/ />
  <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
}

export default MyApp
```

But the drawer will obscure other page contents.
[Obscure other contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vttK.png)

The drawer code is:

```js
// A responsive drawer component that can be clipped to the top or bottom of the screen.

import { Divider, Drawer, List, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, Toolbar, Box, CssBaseline, Paper } from '@mui/material';
import * as React from 'react';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import SearchAppBar from './SearchAppBar';
import DownloadingIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Downloading';
import GradingIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Grading';
import PublishedWithChangesIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PublishedWithChanges';
import UnpublishedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Unpublished';
import CoffeeMakerIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CoffeeMaker';

const drawerWidth = 240;

interface Props {
    window?: () => Window;
}

export default function ClippedDrawer(props: Props) {
    const {window} = props;
    const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
    };

    const drawer = (
        <div>
            <Toolbar />
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['Main'].map((text) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton >
                            <ListItemIcon >
                                <HomeIcon /> 
                                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ mx: 1.5}} />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['Mined Blocks', 'Pending Blocks'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {index % 2 === 0 ? <GradingIcon/> : <DownloadingIcon/>}
                                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ mx: 1.5}} />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
            {['Mined Transactions', 'Pending Transactions'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {index % 2 === 0 ? <PublishedWithChangesIcon/> : <UnpublishedIcon/>}
                                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ mx: 1.5}} />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['Faucet'].map((text) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <CoffeeMakerIcon/>
                                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ mx: 1.5}} />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </div>
    );

    const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;
    
    return (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <SearchAppBar />
            <Box
                component="div"
                sx={{ width : {sm: drawerWidth}, flexShrink: { sm: 0 }}}
                aria-label="Side navigation"
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <Drawer
                        variant='permanent'
                        sx={{
                            display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' },
                            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
                                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                                width: drawerWidth,
                            }
                        }}
                        open
                    >
                        {drawer}
                    </Drawer>
                </Toolbar>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Could you please help me, is there any method to solve this problem? I want to place the page content in the blank space in page. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the Component

```
  return <>
      <ClippedDrawer>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ClippedDrawer>
  </>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried this, but there will be an error said: Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.ts(2559).